# Extract Json properties from a array by value and transform to a new json structure with jq

Tags: json, jq

my input json looks like this:

```
[{
   "methodResponse":{
      "params":{
         "param":{
            "value":{
               "struct":{
                  "member":[
                     {
                        "name":"severity",
                        "value":{
                           "string":"Low"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"product",
                        "value":{
                           "string":"p1"
                        }
                     }                        
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}]
```

I want to extract each "member" entry to a new json object by filtering via "name" value.

Output should be like:

```
[
  {
    "severity": "Low",
    "product": "p1"
  }
]
```

The order of the member items can change.

I'm able to select the values by the "name" value but it doesnt work if the ordering of the member items changed.

```
[.[].methodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member[] | select(.name == "severity").value.string, select(.name == "product").value.string] | [{severity:.[0], product:.[1]}]
```

Another problem is if a member wasnt found by the name value. if a member wasnt found by the name it should print null for the missing member value->  "missingmemberName": null

```
  [
      {
        "severity": "Low",
        "product": "p1",
        "missingmemberName": null
      }
    ]
```

https://jqplay.org/s/CthSsOCQ-Y

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show an object that has a member without name? Your last output `p1` is a valid product name and how can it show up with `missingmemberName`?

Comment: What i meant was that it could be that the name im filtering for isnt there because the input json is dynamic. for example -> im searching for "select(.name == "severity").value.string" -> but in some cases this whole member item isnt there but nevertheless i need the property in my json output with null value then.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the first part of the question as I understand it can be solved by using `from_entries`:

```
.[].methodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member
| map( .value |= .string )
| [from_entries]
```

If you want to select a particular product or products, it would be easy to modify the above.

The second part of the question isn't too clear to me but I think that once you understand `from_entries`, you should be able to find a solution quite easily.

Comment: i cant use map(.value |= .string) because sometimes the structure differs. For Example value.i4 instead of value.string      {
                        "name":"id",
                        "value":{
                           "i4":"12345"
                        }
                     }

Comment: i think i got it, ty -> .[].methodResponse.params.param.value.struct.member |  [map({(.name):(.value.string//.value.i4)})|add]